# Why deleting a file in windows re-spin / wake up / power up all the hard drives?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, power-management, recycle-bin

If I delete a file on HD 1, and HD 2 is sleeping (power down), windows spins it up for some reason. I'm using the regular recyle bin.

Turning off the recycle bin for all partitions on HD 2 won't help as well, it still gets waken.

Windows 7 SP1

Comment: Have a look at this old question: http://superuser.com/questions/560805/why-is-windows-constantly-spinning-up-my-secondary-hdd