# Hard drive spins up randomly without any activity in Resource Monitor

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1

I'm running Windows 8.1 and recently added a secondary internal WD Green hard drive to my rig.

The HDD spins up at random intervals which is very noticeable because it is the noisiest part of the PC.

I tried to figure out the reason but haven't come up with anything:

- Indexing is disabled for the drive
- Pagefiles aren't on the drive
- Monitoring with ResMon reveals no writes to the drive when it powers up

Any ideas what is causing this?

EDIT: Not a duplicat of [Why is Windows constantly spinning up my secondary HDD?](https://superuser.com/questions/560805/why-is-windows-constantly-spinning-up-my-secondary-hdd/) because there the problem was solved via ResMon. 
This does not work for my problem.

EDIT 2: It seems like Windows' Automatic Maintenance (which can't be switched off) does not show up in ResMon, so this might be the culprit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of Why Is Windows Constantly Spinning Up My Secondary HDD: http://superuser.com/questions/560805/why-is-windows-constantly-spinning-up-my-secondary-hdd/

Comment: @Peter.Krahe: I'd like to know what HDDs/fans you run to make the HDD not the noisiest part...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to disable windows automatic maintenance to test to see if that is the answer.  http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/34374-automatic-maintenance-enable-disable-windows-8-a.html

Comment: Nah, it's not so easy the Maintenance Configurator re-enables the Maintenance Service.