# How can I disable auto-reading on DVD-ROM?

Tags: windows-7, windows, dvd, compact-disc

I almost always have a DVD disk of a TV show in my DVD-ROM so I can watch an episode of the show whenever I find the time.

But the DVD-ROM sometimes starts reading/scanning (the sound of spinning the disk.. if you know what I mean) the disk even though I don't need it to.

Can I make the DVD-ROM to not spin (read) the disk unless I express my direct request for reading the disk?

Comment: Yeah, take the disk out until you want to use it.  When you want to give it a "direct request" to get it reading again, put a disk in it.  Problem solved!  ;) Otherwise you're going to need to determine exactly what's accessing the drive, causing it to spin up, and then stoop that from happening. Perhaps checkout [Why is Windows constantly spinning up my secondary HDD?](http://superuser.com/questions/560805/why-is-windows-constantly-spinning-up-my-secondary-hdd) to get started.

Comment: Any time you open Windows Explorer, or anything that looks at the computer (like an open file dialog), it is going to spin up the drive to see what is on it. Techie007 is right. Only way to avoid it is to remove it.

Comment: If you really want to leave it in there and not hav it spin up, you can open Device Manager > DVD/CD-ROM Drives > Right click your drive and choose `Disable`. Once you want to use it, enable it. Otherwise, not much you can do because explorer loves it some CDs

Comment: Only other way besides Nazard's comment is to leave the tray open (only hangs out a little), I do this on my laptops that are stationary, close it when I move it to another location, then re open.

Comment: Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > AutoPlay > Untick 'Use autoplay for all media and devices'
now all autoplay / autorun is disabled.